# fillcover red in initializer dependencies - Quarkus native

Tags: native, quarkus, graalvm

I try to build a native container with Quarkus (with -Pnative flag), I use -H:+PrintClassInitialization to generate the class initializer reports. I see a initilizer_dependencies_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.dot file is generated; in this file, I see some classes marked with [fillcover=red], could you tell me what this means? and what action is needed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me those classes are the ones that will be called but not in reflection configuration. I add them in reflection or initialize to solve it.